# Template Method Checker

Tags: c++, c++11, template, template-meta-programming

I have written some template helpers to check if a class has a certain method with a certain signature. The code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824239). I attempted to extend it for generic methods. An important feature is that it also detects inherited methods.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename, typename, typename T>
struct has_method {
    static_assert(std::integral_constant<T, false>::value,
                  "Third template parameter needs to be of function type.");
};

template <typename C, class caller, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_method<C, caller, Ret(Args...)> {
   private:
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T *) ->
        typename std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<caller>().template call<T>(
                                  std::declval<Args>()...)),
                              Ret>::type
    {
        return typename std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<caller>().template call<T>(
                std::declval<Args>()...)),
            Ret>::type();
//return to surpresswarnings
    }

    template <typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...)
    {
        return std::false_type();
    };

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

   public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
struct existent_caller {
    template <class T, typename... Args>
    constexpr auto call(Args... args) const
        -> decltype(std::declval<T>().existent(args...))
    {
        return decltype(std::declval<T>().existent(args...))();
//return to surpresswarnings
    }
};
struct nonexsistent_caller {
    template <class T, typename... Args>
    constexpr auto call(Args... args) const
        -> decltype(std::declval<T>().nonexsistent(args...));
};
struct X {
    int existent(const std::string &) { return 42; }
};

struct Y : X {
};

struct Z {
};
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    static_assert(
        has_method<X, existent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should have existent method");
    static_assert(
        has_method<Y, existent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should have existent method");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<Z, existent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should not have existent method");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<X, nonexsistent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should not have nonexistent method");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<Y, nonexsistent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should not have nonexistent method");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<Z, nonexsistent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should not have nonexistent method");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<X, existent_caller, double(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should have wrong signature");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<Y, existent_caller, double(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should have wrong signature");
    static_assert(
        !has_method<Z, existent_caller, double(const std::string &)>::value,
        "Should not have method");
    static_assert(!has_method<X, existent_caller, int(double)>::value,
                  "Should have wrong signature");
    static_assert(!has_method<Y, existent_caller, int(double)>::value,
                  "Should have wrong signature");
    static_assert(!has_method<Z, existent_caller, int(double)>::value,
                  "Should not have method");

    std::cout << has_method<Y, existent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value
              << "\n";  // will print 1
    std::cout << has_method<Z, existent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value
              << "\n";  // will print 0

    std::cout
        << has_method<Y, nonexsistent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value
        << "\n";  // will print 0
    std::cout
        << has_method<Z, nonexsistent_caller, int(const std::string &)>::value
        << "\n";  // will print 0
    return 0;
}
```

(the `cout`s are only for assurance)

So far it works, but my concern is the way the callers are defined. The `decltype` stuff is not easy to read. Does someone have ideas on how to give it a cleaner "interface" (or however you would call it)?

Comment: I won't make an answer out of this, but a [function detection toolkit](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf) has been proposed for inclusion into the standard library. You could use some of the ideas exploited in there.

Comment: Please do not change the code once answered, that's against the site policies for it may invalidate the answers. Please see [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Compiler warnings

I compiled your code with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and they managed to trigger some warnings:

- You have an extra comma at the end of the function `static constexpr std::false_type check(...)`. Get rid of it.
- You're not using `argc` nor `argv`. You might want to simply use `int main()` if you're not going to use the parameters.

> *Always request more warnings, never ignore them.*
>   -- Morwenn, 2015-06-11
>
> *That quote was totally unoriginal.*
>   -- Morwenn, same day

## Other miscellaneous stuff

There isn't much to say, so I will only nitpick as I usually do :)

- You don't need the methods `check` to have a definition since you only use them for their signature. Remove their body and let them undefined, it will make it clearer why they exist. This also holds for `existent_caller<>::call`.

  Alternatively, you can use the [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) syntax instead if not providing the body triggers some warnings so that you don't have to repeat the return type:

  ```
  static constexpr auto check(T *) ->
      typename std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<caller>().template call<T>(
                                std::declval<Args>()...)),
                            Ret>::type
  {
      // Default-construct an instance of the return type
      return {};
  }
  ```
- `typedef` is a bit old-fashioned and subjectively not that much readable. You could use the new type alias with `using` instead:

  ```
  using type = decltype(check<C>(0));
  ```
- By the way, `check` takes a *pointer*, make it clear by passing `nullptr` instead of `0`:

  ```
  using type = decltype(check<C>(nullptr));
  ```
- Your methods in `existentcaller` and `nonexistentcaller` could be `static`. It seems that you don't need them to be regular methods.
- Also, you don't need to `return 0;` at the end of `main`. If the compiler reaches the end of `main` without finding a `return` statement, it automagically return 0. Removing `return 0;` is a way to document that your program can't return anything else than 0 from and that it should never return error codes.

Comment: Hi I guess you compile with gcc? If I leave out the return clang++ gives me a lot of warnings that the functions are not defined.

Comment: @MagunRa I tried both GCC and Clang thanks to Coliru :)

Comment: I have changed it but clang++ gives me a lot of warnings like this: `warning: inline function 'existent_caller::call<X, std::basic_string<char> >' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]`

Comment: @MagunRa I included another method that shouldn't give you warnings anymore (and tested with both compilers) :)

Comment: Nice. This does get rid off the warnings.